# In Objective-C/XCode, how can I use a custom Cocoa Framework that defines a protocol within Command Line Tools project?

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks, protocols

When I'm coding a Command Line Tool with Objective-C/XCode, how can I import and make use of a custom Cocoa Framework that defines a protocol? In resume, I must define the main.m class as delegator of the imported framework class.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        // throws error warning: "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'...
        // How can I pass main.m class here?
        MyFrameworkClass *client = [MyFrameworkClass alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyFrameworkClass *client = [MyFrameworkClass alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

Even if you correct the code above to have the correct number of left brackets (`[`), you cannot use `self` in your `main()` function because `main()` is a function, not a method of some object. If you need a delegate for `MyFrameworkClass`, you'll need to first create one, like:

```
SomeDelegateClass *delegate = [[SomeDelegateClass alloc] init];
MyFrameworkClass *client = [[MyFrameworkClass alloc] initWithDelegate:delegate];
```

An a GUI application, you typically have an application delegate that fills this role, and that object is usually instantiated for you by some framework function like `UIApplicationMain()` or `NSApplicationMain()`. You don't have that in a common line program, so you need to do it yourself.

Be careful, however, that you're not misusing the Cocoa framework. Many parts of Cocoa expect a certain context, such as a run loop, and using the framework outside of the usual GUI application context will cause problems. You might want to read up on the Cocoa app startup process in Matt Gallagher's blog post, [*Cocoa Application Startup*](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/cocoa-application-startup.html).